# PHP returns Invalid Request Error

Tags: php, android

I am saving data from Android device to MySQL. My code works fine using Localhost, but when I try it using my hosted domain. It gives me and error.

**Error returned**

```
ERROR
The requested URL could not be retrieved

While trying to process the request:

POST /insert.php HTTP/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: mydomain.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)

The following error was encountered:
Invalid Request
```

**Java code inside AsyncTask**

```
.
.
.
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id", userId));
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://mydomain.com/insert.php");
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

UrlEncodedFormEntity urlEncodeFormEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs);
urlEncodeFormEntity.setChunked(true);

httppost.setEntity(urlEncodeFormEntity);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
.
.
.
```

Please help me solved this problem. Again it working using Localhost.

**EDIT:**

**PHP Code: this is just to test if my device can reach the given URL**

```
<?php
    echo "Ive been reached.";
    //Codes to connect DB and To Insert goes here
?>
```

Comment: can you provide insert.php code here and logcat also?

Comment: @MishuCn I think php codes aren't necessary to post, but as you requested it. I post my php code. Any help are greatly appreciated. Please help me guys.

Comment: No Error nor Exception found in Logcat, "The requested URL could not be retrieved ..." is the value of the HttpResonse.

Comment: can you please try your http://mydomain.com/insert.php in normal browser?just checking the url is it ok or not. it seems url not reached.

Comment: Yeah i tried it on device browser and PC browser, it works perfectly.

Comment: ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1); here you should put number of value you are posting here you are posting one value "user_id" so it should be 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by removing the line

```
urlEncodeFormEntity.setChunked(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://exampple.com/insert-data.php");
 List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "1"));
 try{
  httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
  ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

  String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

  String reverseString = response;

  Log.d("Mishu Complain",reverseString);
 } catch(Exception e){ // check error here  }
```

to find anyerror in log you can put this code

```
catch (Exception anyError) {
             Log.e("Mishu-Cn-Error", "exception",anyError);

        }
```

Comment: W/System.err(5751): org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Length Required
W/System.err(5751):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:71)
W/System.err(5751):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:59)
W/System.err(5751):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:657)

Comment: wait do you have this permission on AndroidManifest.xml <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

Comment: yeah i have that permission in Manifest

Comment: this is the full error log: 08-24 11:46:17.335: W/System.err(10003): org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Length Required
08-24 11:46:17.335: W/System.err(10003):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:71)
08-24 11:46:17.335: W/System.err(10003):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:59)

Comment: 08-24 11:46:17.335: W/System.err(10003):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:657)
08-24 11:46:17.335: W/System.err(10003):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:627)
08-24 11:46:17.340: W/System.err(10003):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:616)

Comment: are u using exact same code i provided then it should work.cause i have a live application using that code and its work fine. and the final one thing remain. does your url need authorization to access the script? check this issue otherswise i have to say "I quite". sorry cant help you anymore cause i m not an expert android programmer